# Magento: How to add onsubmit to form

Tags: magento

I'm adding javascript file with functions in local.xml. I have created form with one custom field type. It's similar to multiselect but it's custom (I'm using my own class to render it). I would like to select all options from this field before submiting form(on submit event), but I can't get it work.

I think everyone know how to add javascript file in xml and how to add custom field type to form, so I'll skip these files.

Here is my form file:

```
class MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    /**
     * Preparing form
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                'id' => 'edit_form',
                'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                'method' => 'post',
                'onsubmit' => "selectAllOptions(document.getElementById('MY_FORM_FIELD_NAME'))", // <---- this on submit doesn't work
            )
        );

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Here is SelectAllOptions function

```
function selectAllOptions(obj) {

    if (!obj.options.length) {
        return;
    }
    for (var i=0; i<obj.options.length; i++)
    {
        obj.options[i].selected = true;
    }

}
```

Im able to call this function in Firebug console and it work that way. But when I press Save button in magento form, this function is not even executed.
I think that's because all magento buttons look like this:

```
<button style="" onclick="editForm.submit();" class="scalable save" type="button" title="Test" id="id_822f4065958eef93a184bed0e17ab443"><span><span><span>Test</span></span></span></button>
```

And because of method **onclick="editForm.submit()"** my function is not triggered.

I'm just starting learning magento and I would be glad if some more experienced developer told me how to use onsubmit.

I checked Varien_Data_Form class and there is method

```
/**
 * Return allowed HTML form attributes
 * @return array
 */
public function getHtmlAttributes()
{
    return array('id', 'name', 'method', 'action', 'enctype', 'class', 'onsubmit');

}
```

So adding function to onsubmit should be allowed.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have anywhere code that is adding button element to this form?
Because when i test it with your code i have no problem creating the form with the correct html, and with onsubmit as attribute of the form, however it does not have submit button. Also inspect the html that this form code is dumping. Your function should be in the onsubmit attribute of the form

Answer (score 0):

I think the trick is to override `onsubmit` on the button since that is causing a problem, and that happens in the form's container, not the form itself.

```
class MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    /**
     * Need to change save button here
     */
    protected function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->updateButton(
            'save',
            'onsubmit',
            "selectAllOptions($('MY_FORM_FIELD_NAME'));"
            // in Prototype $ is equivalent to document.getElementById
        );
    }
}
```